# ExpressJS - Displaying AJAX response on webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I am doing a username availability. I am taking in the Username from a js file and sending in an AJAX POST call into a route and checking the database with the entered username. The DB logic is working fine. I am sending back the information in the following way back to the AJAX call:

```
if(err){ 
        console.log("Error checking username availability...")
    }
    if(doc && doc._id){ 
        console.log(doc.lastname+ " User aleady Exists")
    }  else {

     res.send({result: "Username Available"})
}
```

And this is the file `main.js` that has the AJAX POST call:

```
$("input[name='username']").blur(function(){
//enteredUsername = $("input[name='username']").val()

var data={}
data.enteredUsername = $("input[name='username']").val()
alert(data.enteredUsername)
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/checkUsername',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result){
        render(result);
    }
}

// }).done(function ( result ) {
//      alert("ajax callback response:"+JSON.stringify(result));
//   })

 });
```

I tried it doing in different ways
1) I Tried a `success` function in AJAX, which is not working
2) I tried it using `.done()` which was also not working

for the sake of clarity, this is my username field in User Registration file (a `.ejs` file):

```html
<input type="text" name="username" required="required" minlength="6">
        <script src="scripts/main.js">

        </script>
        <%= result %>
```

Any help/assistance appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Express

```js
// Magic
...
if(err){ 
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
          error: true
          ,message: 'Error checking username availability...'
        }))
    }
    if(doc && doc._id){ 
        console.log(doc.lastname+ " User aleady Exists")
    }  else {

     res.end({
      error: false
      ,result: "Username Available"
     })
}
```

Front end

```js
// AJAX Maigc
...

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/checkUsername',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result){
        
        if(result.error === false){
          // Success
          render(result);
        }else{
          const errorMessage = result.message;
          // Work your way
        }
        
    }
}

 });
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` the last `res.end()` also right...?. I fixed that part and ran, Its not displaying the username available message on the page....how does this answer my question?...